# Python trigonometric calculations in degrees

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am converting a MATLAB program to Python for a project. I am facing some major issues with converting MATLAB's `sind()` syntax to Python. I'm using

```
numpy.sin(numpy.radians())
```

but some of the results in Python compared to `Matlab` are displaying tremendous variations. Is there an easier way to tell Python in degrees instead of radians?

Comment: What you need is `numpy.deg2rad`, or just `deg_array/180*np.pi`. As far as I know `numpy.sin` will only accept radians as input.

Comment: You have a bug somewhere. We can't tell what it is. Converting degrees to radians with `numpy.radians` and computing the sine with `numpy.sin` should not cause catastrophic error relative to a function that takes degrees directly.

Comment: Nevermind, I had no idea that there was an equivalent `numpy.radians`, sorry.

Comment: Can you show examples of problematic input and corresponding output?

Comment: why are you using numpy.sin? I normally use `from math import sin, pi` and then something like `sin(30*pi/180.)` will give me what I want.

Answer (score 3):

In Octave, `sind` is:

```
function y = sind (x)
  ...
  I = x / 180;
  y = sin (I .* pi);
  y(I == fix (I) & isfinite (I)) = 0;
endfunction
```

`np.radians` (`np.deg2rad`) is, according to a note `x * pi / 180`.

So for most values `np.sin(np.radians(x))` should be the same as `sind(x)`.  There might be some variation off at the limits of floating point precision.  Also I'm not sure what that last line is supposed to be doing.

```
In [327]: np.sin(np.radians(0))
Out[327]: 0.0
In [328]: np.sin(np.radians(90))
Out[328]: 1.0
In [329]: np.sin(np.radians(180))
Out[329]: 1.2246467991473532e-16

>> sind(0)
ans = 0
>> sind(90)
ans =  1
>> sind(180)
ans = 0
```

The Octave docs add: `Returns zero for elements where 'X/180' is an integer.`

So yes there may be differences, but 1e-16 is not a tremendous difference.

I can replicate `sind` with:

```
def sind(x):
    I = x/180.
    y = np.sin(I * np.pi)
    mask = (I == np.trunc(I)) & np.isfinite(I)
    y[mask] = 0
    return y

In [356]: x=np.array([0,90,180,359,360])
In [357]: np.sin(np.radians(x))
Out[357]: 
array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.22464680e-16,
        -1.74524064e-02,  -2.44929360e-16])
In [358]: sind(x)
Out[358]: array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        , -0.01745241,  0.        ])

>> x=[0,90,180,359, 360]
x =
     0    90   180   359   360
>> sind(x)
ans =
   0.00000   1.00000   0.00000  -0.01745   0.00000
```